# hibernate restriction on date issue

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am facing issue in hibernate criteria restriction. I have data in db2 table as 2014-03-05 20:07:33 and I am trying to fetch data based on the below criteria:

```
hibernateCriteria.add(Restrictions.ge("eventTs",
            getLowerBoundDate(adminReportsBeanDTO.getFromDate())));
    hibernateCriteria.add(Restrictions.le("eventTs",
            getUpperBoundDate(adminReportsBeanDTO.getToDate())));
public static Date getLowerBoundDate(Date fromDate) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(fromDate);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    return cal.getTime();
}

/**
 * 
 * @param fromDate
 * @return
 */
public static Date getUpperBoundDate(Date toDate) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(toDate);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);
    return cal.getTime();
}
```

and from date is as Wed Mar 05 00:00:00 IST 2014 and to date is Wed Mar 05 23:59:59 IST 2014

and I have records in the table for the above date but it is not displaying. But the report is displaying for the next date 6th march.

here is my hibernate criteria

```
CriteriaImpl(com.gtech.lsp.beans.Audit:this[][eventTs>=Wed Mar 05 00:00:00 IST 2014,            eventTs<=Wed Mar 05 23:59:59 IST 2014])
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're comparing dates in different timezones! Your Java Calendar are set in Indian timezone (IST). What about the dates in database?
Try setting your Calendar timezone to GMT if this is your database timezone:

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
cal.setTimeZone(tz);
```

Comment: the db is in USA and my application is in India

Comment: BUt do you know the type of your date column? If it is timestamp that mean a timezone could have been set in the data.

Comment: Yes, the data type is timestamp

Comment: Then a timezone must have been saved in your dates. Do a simple sql query on your table to fetch the dates, you should be able to see it.

Comment: I don't see the timezone. This is the output of the date column.

   2014-03-05 20:07:33
2014-03-05 19:44:54
2014-03-05 19:44:59
2014-03-05 19:45:06
2014-03-05 19:45:13
2014-03-05 19:45:19
2014-03-05 20:15:01
2014-03-05 20:15:04
2014-03-05 20:15:11
2014-03-05 20:15:16
2014-03-05 20:15:23
2014-03-05 20:37:20

Comment: My issue is: I am inserting user activities on the application into the table for the audit purpose.So there is report to see these details with the from date and end date input.Suppose today do some activities on the application like user login,edit user etc. These will be stored in the table with the current date. But if I want to view the report by entering the fromdate(6th march 2014) and to date(6th march 2014) as current date, it is not displaying the report. But next day(7th March 2014) if I select from date(6th March 2014) and to date(6th March 2014),it is displaying the 6th day report

Comment: Have you tried playing around with the timezone on the Calendar object as I wrote earlier? Try setting the timezone to GMT or PST (Pacific Time) to see if it influences your results.